# How to append a string to visudo?

Tags: linux, command, devops

I want to edit visudo by appending a string to it.
let say the string is 'String to be appended'
I have tried

```
echo 'string to be appended' >>sudo visudo
```

but its not working

please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: visudo is designed to be interactive and provide interactive lock and sanity checks. If you really want to append a line, you can append the line to the file as you would any file but you risk errors. A better approach would be to use something like Ansible with Jinja templates

Comment: You would need to use a | (pipe) instead of >>. But even then it will not work for the reason the comment above explains.